# Derive the solution of the Ordinary Differental Equation

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions

Derive the solution this Ordinary Differential Equation

$$ f(x) =  \frac {d^2y}{dx^2} , \ x>0, \ y(0) = 0, \frac{dy}{dx}(0) = 0 \ in \ the \ form: y(x) = \int_{0}^\infty h(t)dt$$ for a function h which I should determine in a simple form

Comment: $h$ must be a function of $x$ as well as $t$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Also, please address the comment from @RobertIsrael.